# Flutter android library and iOS framework

Tags: android, ios, flutter, libraries, aar

My question is, how do I use .aar files for android and iOS frameworks in flutter?

I am coding a program and I am using flutter. I found .aar files for program and iOS frameworks. How do I integrate both and use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to use method channel so you can call native code and can connect from Flutter to Android and iOS. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thanks, that is what was I looking for!